# How to assign a subset of a tensor but still keep the original tensor?

Tags: pytorch

I want to zero the main diagonal of the tensor `exp_scaled_pcs`, and by doing so I don't want the original tensor to change but I want to receive the output of the assignment into a new tensor `zero_sim_exp_scaled_pcs`.

By doing:

```py
zero_sim_exp_scaled_pcs = torch.diagonal(exp_scaled_pcs, 0).zero_()
```

I noted that I change my original tensor also. How can I keep it?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Tensor.index_put`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.index_put)

```py
x = torch.randn(10, 10)

d = min(x.shape)
diag_indices = [torch.arange(d)] * x.dim()
y = x.index_put(diag_indices, torch.zeros(d))
```

Comment: And what if d is unknown?

Comment: You have the tensor so you should be able to get the shape of it with `Tensor.shape`.